# Google Sheets App Script lock cells for specific days

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to unlock certain range of cells on every month for the first 10 days and after that lock the range until next month. Here is what I've been working on. But this doesn't work as i expected. Any help is appreciated.

```
function tenDaysAllowance() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Online Allowance");
  var todaysdate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT+5', 'dd/MM/yyyy');
  var firstDate = new Date();
  var fd = firstDate;
    fd.setMonth(fd.getMonth());
    fd.setDate(1);
  var td = new Date();
    td.setMonth(td.getMonth());
    td.setDate(10);
  var firstDay = Utilities.formatDate(fd, 'GMT+5', 'dd/MM/yyyy');
  var afterTen = Utilities.formatDate(td, 'GMT+5', 'dd/MM/yyyy');
  Logger.log(firstDay);
  Logger.log(afterTen);

  if (todaysdate >= firstDay && todaysdate <= afterTen) {
    Logger.log("todays date is in range");
    var range = ss.getRange('B27:AF40');
    var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');
    var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
    protection.addEditor(me);
    protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
    if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
      protection.setDomainEdit(false);
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log("todays date is not in range");
    var range = ss.getRange('B27:AF40');
    var allProtections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
    var matchingProtections = allProtections.filter(function(existingProtection) {
    return existingProtection.getRange().getA1Notation() == 'B27:AF40';
    });
    var protection = matchingProtections[0];
    protection.remove();
    };
};
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `I am trying to unlock certain range of cells on every month for the first 10 days and after that lock the range until next month.` and your showing script, I cannot understand your actual goal. From your explanation of your goal, in this case, for example, do you want to run the script using the time-driven trigger? And also, from `But this doesn't work as i expected.`, I cannot understand the detail of your current issue. So, can you provide the detail of both your goal and your current issue?

Comment: I want to make a range editable to others on the first 10 days of each month and lock the range on 11th day.

Comment: Hey Keto, your code seems to be doing the opposite. The first half actually prevents people from editing in the first 10 days. I think just need to switch the order.

Comment: Regarding your issue, I would implement a simple if condition using the date value of the month to check. Answer posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your google sheet use a `today()` to determine today's date and `day()` to determine value of today's date.

[image]

```
function myProtection() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Date Check");
var date=ss.getRange("B1");

//if it more the 10th of the month lock sheet, else allow others to edit
if(date > 10)
{
// Protect range A1:B10, then remove all other users from the list of editors.
var range = ss.getRange('B27:AF40');
var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');
var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
protection.addEditor(me);
protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
protection.setDomainEdit(false);
}
}


else{
    var allProtections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
    var matchingProtections = allProtections.filter(function(existingProtection) {
    return existingProtection.getRange().getA1Notation() == 'B27:AF40';
    });
    var protection = matchingProtections[0];
    protection.remove();
};
}
```